# Amazon MQ Workshop Unable to complete setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloud9

I followed the setup guide for *Cloud9 IDE Workspace setup* for Amazon MQ workshop. When I ran `./setup.sh`
I got the following output but the setup could not be completed:

```
Installing jq...
Updating java to 1.8...
Updating maven to 3.6...
```

There was no error, just the 3 lines and I waited forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the setup file tried to download maven from `http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/maven/maven-3/3.6.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz` but the site could not be reached.

The solution was to edit `setup.sh` file and replace the URL with the direct link from apache website

`https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tired it and it worked for me. @Wakeel